# What are ttdef.h and tt2def.h in the C programming language?

Tags: c

I'm reading the source code for a text editor application (Torvalds/uemacs on GitHub.com). There is a certain file (termio.c) that [`#include`s](https://github.com/torvalds/uemacs/blob/1cdcf9df88144049750116e36fe20c8c39fa2517/termio.c#L18) the contents of files such as: stsdef.h, ssdef.h, descript.h, iodef.h, ttdef.h and tt2def.h. I have absolutely no clue what these header files contain or what they are used for. Can anyone refer me to any material I can read to understand what these are?

Comment: You should look into the documentation of the project for a description - if it exists. Or you can find the respective files in the repository and study them.

Comment: To link to github, click on a line number on a file viewer, then click on the [...] button on the left and choose "Copy permalink"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These headers are specific for the VMS operating system. They're guarded by **both** `#ifndef POSIX` and `#ifdef VMS`. They contain the [terminal bps settings and alike](https://fossies.org/dox/freevms-0_3_15/ttdef_8h.html) for *this operating system*. The files do not exist in Unixen or Windows, and are not needed there to compile uemacs.